# iPhone 6s camera replacement

Tags: iphone, ios, camera, repair

I dropped my iPhone and shattered the external lens. The internal one was scratched, too.

I got the parts online and followed the *iFixit* guide to open up my iPhone and replace the camera. Now when I to the *Camera* app I only capture the top pixels.  The photos come out like the image below.  Do you think I got a defective camera unit or am I missing something?

[image: iphone photo]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I would do, in order:

1. Restart the iPhone
2. Open the iPhone up, disconnect the camera, and reconnect it
3. Clean the contacts on the logic board with isopropyl alcohol (with the battery disconnected, of course)
4. Return the camera and get a new one from a different source

Also, I don't know from where you ordered the camera, but if you have to return it and get a new one, don't just buy the cheapest thing you see. Try to find a seller from your country that cares enough to post real photos of the camera instead of those stock photos and buy one from them.

If the next one still doesn't work, you could try one more from another seller, but if it still doesn't work, then it's the almost certainly the iPhone at fault and about the only thing to do would be get another one if you want the camera fixed.

Comment: Just to follow up, I did return the camera and replace it with a new one that was more expensive, as you suggested. It does work now, although the autofocus does not, I can't get anything to focus close up (for example it's impossible to pair an apple watch with the camera).